# When could the product of two integral becomes a double integral?

Tags: calculus

question1: Why the product of two integral becomes a double integral?

What conditions?

$$\begin{align*}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} \, dx\right)^2=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty}^{\infty }e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dxdy\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{\frac{\left(x^2+y^2\right)}{2}}dxdy\end{align*}$$

The integration should be $1$, however when I changed to Polar form, something wrong.

$$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dxdy=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _0^{2\pi }\int_0^{\infty }\color{red}{-}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2}}rdrd\theta \\&=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _0^{2\pi }e^{\frac{-r^2}{2}}|_0^{\infty }(=-1)d\theta =-1\end{align*}$$

question2:Where goes wrong?

The red `Minus` $\color{red}{}-\text{}$ is wrong?

question3: Can you show me how to convert $\text{dxdy}$ to $\text{rdrd$\theta $}$ in terms of Jacobians?

Comment: Yes, that's it. $dx\,dy = r\,dr\,d\theta$.

Comment: Notice in the last equality on the first line, you drop the negative.

Comment: Where did you take that red minus sign in the middle from? It is wrong...

Comment: @DonAntonio a book named <all math you missed>. It gives the answer $1$, and I give $-1$

Comment: Well, that's wrong @spuorg-imes...or else you missed *another minus sign* before the whole double integral...

Comment: To clarify my earlier comment. The expression should still have a minus sign in the exponent. That way when you switch to polar you do not need the red minus sign that you have. So it should not be there. Then you get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you could have missed:

$$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2}}dxdy=\color{red}-\frac{1}{2\pi }\int _0^{2\pi }\int_0^{\infty }\color{red}{-r}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2}}drd\theta \end{align*}$$

Note that we have then

$$-re^{-\frac{r^2}2}=\frac{d}{dr}\left(-\frac{r^2}2\right)\cdot e^{-\frac{r^2}2}$$

and we use then the following:

$$\int f'(x)e^{f(x)}dx=e^{f(x)}\ldots$$

Comment: Hi, can you show me how to convert $\text{dxdy}$ to $\text{rdrd$\theta $}$, use Jacobian? and also question1, I'm a newbie

Comment: @spuorg-imes, as follows: $$x=r\cos\theta\;,\;y=r\sin\theta\implies$$$$ \frac{dx}{dr}=\cos\theta\;,\;\frac{dx}{d\theta}=-r\sin\theta$$$$\frac{dy}{dr}= \sin\theta\;,\;\frac{dy}{d\theta}=r\cos\theta$$ Thus $$\left|J\frac{(x,y)}{(r,\theta)}\right|=\left|\det\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-r \sin\theta\\\sin\theta&r\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\right|=|r(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2 \theta)|=r$$

Answer (score 0):

Just an answer to the first question:

$$
\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\, dx\right)^2
= \left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\, dx\right) \left(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\, dx\right)
$$

For one of the integrals we can use the dummy variable trick (same as substituting $y=x$)

$$
\left(\int_a^b f(x)\, dx\right) \left(\int_a^b f(y)\, dy\right)
$$

Since both integrals become constants, we can use the multiplication by a constant rule.

$$\int_a^b \int_a^b f(y)\, dy\, f(x)\, dx$$

which can be written as the double integral

$$\int_a^b \int_a^b f(x) f(y)\, dx\, dy$$